# How to recursive parent and child this array of objects

Tags: php

My array of object in JSON

[{
    "UUID": "0",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "user_id": "Z29kbHlpdG5ldHdvcmtAZ21haWwuY29t"
},
{
    "UUID": "2",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "user_id": "person2"
},
{
    "UUID": "3",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "user_id": "person3"
},
{
    "UUID": "4",
    "parent_id": "2",
    "user_id": "person4"
},
{
    "UUID": "5",
    "parent_id": "2",
    "user_id": "person5"
},
{
    "UUID": "6",
    "parent_id": "3",
    "user_id": "person6"
},
{
    "UUID": "7",
    "parent_id": "3",
    "user_id": "person7"
}]

My array of object in JSON (IMAGE)

[image]

I want to recursively sort the parent id to the child.
ending up late a structure like

[image]

Comment: And what you tried?

Comment: I tried doing for loop in a function and return the data and loop again and even tried the array auto creating new array key to the value

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provide json of the array so can decode and can try to achieve your desired output.

Comment: @VidhyutPandya Ok please wait a few minutes, I will create some better data for you to see

Comment: [{
 "UUID": "0",
 "parent_id": "0",
 "user_id": "Z29kbHlpdG5ldHdvcmtAZ21haWwuY29t"
},
{
 "UUID": "2",
 "parent_id": "0",
 "user_id": "person2"
},
{
 "UUID": "3",
 "parent_id": "0",
 "user_id": "person3"
},
{
 "UUID": "4",
 "parent_id": "2",
 "user_id": "person4"
},
{
 "UUID": "5",
 "parent_id": "2",
 "user_id": "person5"
},
{
 "UUID": "6",
 "parent_id": "3",
 "user_id": "person6"
},
{
 "UUID": "7",
 "parent_id": "3",
 "user_id": "person7"
}]